# Mountain Lion firewall is randomly delaying DNS requests

Tags: dns, firewall

I recently experienced some delays during DNS host resolution on OS X 10.8. To test it I started a simple script which tries to repeatedly resolve the same hostname 20 times:

```js
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq 20`; do
    time -p dig www.google.com @8.8.8.8 | grep "^;; Query time:"
done
```

Most request take about the same time as the latency to the name server:

```
;; Query time: 49 msec
real 0.05
```

However, as soon as I enable the firewall in Mountain Lion (all incoming requests are allowed, *stealth mode* is **not** enabled), *some* of the `dig` requests take exactly 5 seconds plus the latency to the name server:

```
;; Query time: 25 msec
real 5.03
```

Most requests are still fast, but around every 10th to 15th requests has a delay of exactly 5 seconds even through `dig` still reports a short query time. It makes no difference if I use `dig` or `host` for testing, or if I use a local DNS server or a public one like in the example above. When the firewall is turned off the delay never happens.

Does the firewall of OS X enforce some kind of rate limiting for requests, or is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: I tested your script and have the exact same behavior. I also think the firewall is doing something here... but since the 5 second pauses look kind of random I have no idea what happens inside. I will investigate it a little more.

Comment: There's now a related Serverfault thread with the same problem (which also links back here): http://serverfault.com/questions/526668/dns-server-responses-and-timeouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. I diagnose the same rate limiting at the firewall level
on MacOS X 10.7.4 (Lion).

Moreover, if you look at

```
/usr/bin/sudo tcpdump -i en0 udp port 53
```

You will notice that the round trip time to get a reply from `8.8.8.8`
is much lower then the 40 msec displayed by the server.

On a long test run I had:

```
;; Query time: 44 msec
```

and an average roundtrip time of 26 msec:

```
09:36:14.360564 IP me.53866 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 9943+ A? www.google.com. (32)
09:36:14.386302 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > me.53866: 9943 5/0/0 A 173.194.41.180, A 173.194.41.178, A 173.194.41.176, A 173.194.41.177, A 173.194.41.179 (112)
```

(386302 - 360564 = 26 msec)

To understand this protection mechanism (against basic DOS), *look* at:

```
/usr/bin/sudo pfctl -i en0 -s timeouts
```

The full documentation of this complex command is [pfctl(8) Mountain Lion reference manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man8/pfctl.8.html)

Beware this is a powerfull but highly dangerous command. You may easily break your network access (Where is my backup?).